# Flutter-Azure Deviops pipelineThe discrepancy between the number of tests reported as passed or failed in the pipeline output and the test report

Tags: flutter, azure, unit-testing, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build Flutter Android pipeline using Azure Devops using classic editors.
I have a task for Flutter test which gives coverage report and publish it as well.
Coverage report is made correctly, but my Test Cases passed/failed report seems wrong.

Attached are the snapshots [image: Test Cases report after running task and Test Report]

[image]

Why there is discrepancy in the number of tasks.
I have 96 passed and one failed but report shows 134 passed.

Kindly help me with this. I might be doing something wrong.

Link referred- https://medium.com/bina-nusantara-it-division/integrate-flutter-code-coverage-report-to-azure-devops-b5d55f457be4

Updated :  junit.xml

```
<testsuite name="auth_model_test.dart" timestamp="2024-02-05T05:11:54.823Z" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0" tests="7">
    <testcase name="loading D:/a/1/s/ISFV2/ericsson_mobile_isf/test/features/authentication/datamodel/auth_model_test.dart" classname="loading D:/a/1/s/ISFV2/ericsson_mobile_isf/test/features/authentication/datamodel/auth_model_test.dart" time="14.657"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModelNotifier Tests Set AuthModel" classname="AuthModelNotifier Tests Set AuthModel" time="0.029"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModelNotifier Tests Clear AuthModel" classname="AuthModelNotifier Tests Clear AuthModel" time="0"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModel Tests AuthModel toMap" classname="AuthModel Tests AuthModel toMap" time="0"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModel Tests AuthModel fromMap" classname="AuthModel Tests AuthModel fromMap" time="0"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModel Tests AuthModel toJson" classname="AuthModel Tests AuthModel toJson" time="0"/>
    <testcase name="AuthModel Tests AuthModel fromJson" classname="AuthModel Tests AuthModel fromJson" time="0"/>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite timestamp="2024-02-05T05:11:54.823Z" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0" tests="1">
    <testcase name="Some tests failed." classname="Some tests failed." time="0"/>
  </testsuite>
```

above is some data from junit.xml file. I see there are test cases added like

testcase name with loading... or some test failed are increasing the counts I guess. But I don't know why this is happening

Comment: Please run flutter test on your local machine and check if the number of tests is correct. If the number is correct, the issue may be related to Flutter task or pipeline. If it's wrong locally, the issue may be related to flutter.

Comment: At the same time, try this extension [Flutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter) published by Aloïs to run flutter test.  This one works for me. But the number of tests is wrong when I use another extension with the same name.

Comment: Locally flutter test gives right count. no issues there. In fact in pipeline also it is correct but in test summary it shows 134. I am using the extension from Alois

Comment: According to the fourth to last line in your screenshot, the number of tests is 134. If you download the generated Junit.xml file, I guess the number of tests in it is also 134. The problem is not that the test tab displays incorrectly, but that there are problems with the generated test result file. You can check the author of the task from the beginning of the log.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT if u can see I have updated in query a few code line from junit.xml file. There are test cases which are added with test case name = some test failed, or loading..... I think that is increasing the count. but why this is happening I don't know .  Also I rechecked I am using flutter extension from Hey24Sheep not by Alios

Comment: Thanks for your update. Can you try [using the extension I shared](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter) and see if you still have the same issue? Using Hey24Sheep's extension I would have the same problem as you, but using Aloïs's extension everything is working fine so far.

Comment: sure @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I will check that and update you here. thanks !!!

Comment: have you tried to use the extension published by Aloïs? Did it work for you? I have shared my test results below for your reference. Hope it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the Flutter extension published by Hey24sheep, I will have the same issue sometime. In my test, there are 8 tests in total, but there are only 6 in the test result.
[image]

When I use [the Flutter extension published by Aloïs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter), everything is working fine so far.
[image]

Comment: hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT , I can see the same number of tests now. Thank you!!!  Also in this extension and in earlier one it counts setUpAll() method if called in tests  written consider it as a test case hence numbers were increasing. Also extension from Alios does not give code coverage. any idea about it ?  or any other way I can give

Comment: 1. "Also in this extension and in earlier one it counts setUpAll() method if called in tests written consider it as a test case" - I'm afraid I don't have any better suggestions. How to calculate the number of test cases depends how the extension works.  2. "extension from Alios does not give code coverage" - Maybe you can use Hey24sheep's extension to generate code coverage and use Alios's extension to get test result. Uncheck the `Publish Test Results` option in Hey24sheep's task.

Comment: Maybe you can use Hey24sheep's extension to generate code coverage and use Alios's extension to get test result. Uncheck the Publish Test Results option in Hey24sheep's task. - but this way the time to build the timeline will be more - 2 time test cases will run. what if test cases is 200,300 in count.

Comment: This seems like a bug in Hey24sheep's extension. I noticed that you have reported an issue to the publisher. It's suggested that you could follow it.  Besides, maybe you can try to run [flutter commands](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli#flutter-commands). I try to run `flutter.bat test --pub --coverage` according to the log of the flutter task. but haven't been able to get the test result file and code coverage repo. Maybe you can investigate and test further. In any case, although using two flutter tasks takes more time, it can at least temporarily achieve your needs.